# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I have a UIView inside of a UIScrollView, both created using IB. The UIView scrolls horizontally inside the UIScrollView. I want to detect left and right 2 finger swipes.

Borrowing from the sample code I found in  [SmpleGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460), I have put the following code in the viewDidLoad method of the UIScrollView's ViewController...

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightRecognizer, *swipeLeftRecognizer;

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
swipeRightRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
swipeRightRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];
[recognizer release];

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
swipeLeftRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
swipeLeftRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

I have  set in the viewcontroller.h. and have the following delegate method...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
   return YES;
}
```

I am assuming this is a valid gestureRecognizer delegate method, but I cannot find any reference to it in the documentation.

I do not get any errors but nothing happens when I do a 2 finger swipe. The delegate method is not called and neither is my action method. I tried removing the numbeOfTouchesRequired call to see if it might work with a single finger swipe to no avail.

Am I adding the gestureRecognizers to the right view? I tried adding it to the UIView, the UIScrollView as well as self.view.superView.

The sample code runs great. The only difference I can see between my implementation of the code and the sample code is the fact that I used IB to create the views and the sample code did not. I suspect that something is consuming the swipe gesture before it gets to my recognizers.

What am I doing wrong.

Thanks,

John

Comment: one thing to remind you gesture recognizer will work only above 3.2 os. Its better to use touches began method to use instead of swipe gesture

Comment: Wait for iOS 5 SDK. UiSwipeGestures are integrated into IB in xcode 4.2 and you can easily connect actions to gestures! That will make it a lot easier!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I solved by using UIPanGestureRecognizer instead of UISwipeGestureRecognizer.

To emulate the detection of swipe, we'll play with the speed of gesture in scrollview.
If the speed of x direction >= 3000 (for example) the swipe will be detected.

If x>0 it will be a right swipe.

The code I implemented to resolve your situation is:
In a uiscrollview named _scroll1:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Swipe4ScrollViews:)];
[pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
[_scroll1 addGestureRecognizer:pan];
[pan release];
```

With a global BOOL variable named _panning, Swipe4ScrollViews will do the hard job:

```
-(void)Swipe4ScrollViews:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) _panning = NO;

    CGPoint v =[sender velocityInView:_scroll1];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f",v.x,v.y);

    if( (abs(v.x) >= UMBRAL) && !_panning)
    {
        _panning = YES;
        [sender cancelsTouchesInView];

        if(v.x>0) NSLog(@"Right");
        else NSLog(@"Left");

        [self doSomething];
    }
}
```

I encapsulated it on a UIGestureRecognizer subclass: [UISwipe4ScrollGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/iz3/UISwipe4ScrollGestureRecognizer)

Comment: Jose, Thanks for this. I will try your method out and get back to you as to how it worked for me. thanks again. John

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between the sample code and your code is that your code involves a `UIScrollView`.

Internally, scroll views, table views, and web views all use gesture recognizers to some degree. If you're expecting to receive gestures *within* those views – gestures that are similar to the ones already supported internally – they will almost certainly be consumed or significantly delayed before you can get to them. Receiving gestures *outside* or *above* those views should work fine, if your use case supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the delayContentTouches-property of the UIScrollView to NO, maybe it'll help.