# Using UISwipeGestureRecognizer in UIScrollView, can't detect right swipe, only detect left swipe

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a UIView *demoView* in a UIScrollView.  I want to scroll the UIScroll view vertically and don't scroll horizontally.  I add UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the UIView.  The code is (self here is the UIScrollView):

```
self.demoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeLineChart:)];
rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.demoView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeLineChart:)];
[self.demoView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
```

The result is I can only detect the left swipe gesture, can't detect right swipe gesture.  What's wrong with my code?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `self` here is the view controller?

Comment: self here is a UIScrollView's subclass.  I use a .xib file.  this subclass is bundled with the .xib.

Comment: Why are do add swipe recognizers at all? If you don't want your scroll view to scroll horizontally you should specify contentSize with 0 width (or less then viewport width).

Answer (score 1):

The default value of UISwipeGestureRecognizer direction property is UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight so you are creating two recognizers that does the same thing.

This is how i would solve the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onGestureSwipe:)];
    swipeRecognizer.direction = (i == 0 ? UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight : UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft);
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect a swipe into a UIScrollView or a UIWebView is hard. You can use "Swipe4ScrollViews" from here:
[UISwipeGestureRecognizer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407171/uiswipegesturerecognizer-not-working/6937646#6937646)