# How to make UISwipeGestureRecognizer work in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

What I have is this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideHeaderBar:)];
swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
swipeUp.

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
```

And then I have a `UIScrollView` in the view. For some reason when I scroll up on the scroll view, it does not call the select `hideHeaderBar`. Are there any fixes to this?

```
-(void)hideHeaderBar:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeRecognizer{
    POPSpringAnimation *fadeButton = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerOpacity];
    fadeButton.toValue = @(0.0);
    fadeButton.springBounciness = 0.f;

    [settingsButton.layer pop_addAnimation:fadeButton forKey:@"fadeButton"];
    [heartButton.layer pop_addAnimation:fadeButton forKey:@"fadeButton"];
    [conversationsButton.layer pop_addAnimation:fadeButton forKey:@"fadeButton"];

    POPSpringAnimation *hideHeader = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionY];
    hideHeader.toValue = @(-10);
    hideHeader.springBounciness = 5.f;
    [headerBar.layer pop_addAnimation:hideHeader forKey:@"hideHeaderAnim"];
    POPSpringAnimation *hideBody = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewFrame];
    hideBody.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, -10, screenSize.size.width, screenSize.size.height)];
    hideBody.springBounciness = 5.f;
    [homeScrollView.layer pop_addAnimation:hideBody forKey:@"hideBodyAnim"];


}
```

One thing to note is that the `UIScrollView` is in a child view controller (which is inside a `UIScrollView` itself)

```
[self addChildViewController:settingsViewController];
[homeScrollView addSubview:settingsViewController.view];
[settingsViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.size.width, screenSize.size.height)];
[settingsViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Show me your Target @(hideHeaderBar:)

Comment: ==> here is post it will helpful to you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407171/uiswipegesturerecognizer-not-working/6937646#6937646

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you might be able to use a swipe gesture recognizer, but scroll views already handle swipes.

What's likely *better* and *more appropriate* to do here is to set your view controller to be a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement this method:

[`scrollViewDidScroll:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:)

To detect only the times when your scrolling is going up, you can add a property to your view controller that looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lastContentOffset;
```

and simply do something like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scrolling Up");
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scrolling Down");
    }

    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

(the above code I found [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480436/ios-uicollectionview-detect-scroll-direction))

When the "Scrolling up" line appears, there's the time to hide your header bar.

Comment: Great! It calls my hideHeaderBar more than I want it to but it works. Also when it bounces to the top it will showHeaderBar.

Comment: If you added a "`lastTimeCalledHideHeaderBar`" property, you can probably figure out a way to throttle how often hideHeaderBar is called (e.g. only call the functionality of hideHeaderBar after some time interval).

Comment: Perfect! I've made it a "lastTimeCalledHideHeaderBar" a boolean and just make an if statement to avoid the call to it numerous times.

Comment: Also using 
- scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset: and the velocity property to detect scrolling up or down which fixes the bounces!

Answer (score 0):

Because i think you have set content-size(height) is more than scrollview height so when you swipe up default scroll method for scrollview is called. and your hideHeaderBar not called. so either you have to stop scrolling or set its content height less then scrollview but after that scrollview will be meaning less(its become same as view). so i just say it for your test .